# Transform function using Momentjs

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, momentjs

Its there a way to transform this function to moment.js? its like 70% js and 30% moment.js

**Function**

```
 function muestraDias() { 
var day=0; 
var server = TimeSync.serverTime() // 
var d= new Date(); 

var weekdays = new Array(7);
weekdays[0] = "Domingo";
weekdays[1] = "Lunes";
weekdays[2] = "Martes";
weekdays[3] = "Miercoles";
weekdays[4] = "Jueves";
weekdays[5] = "Viernes";
weekdays[6] = "Sabado";
 for (i=1; i<8;i++){  
          document.getElementById("sub"+i).innerHTML = moment(d).locale("es").format('L');  
          day=weekdays[d.getDay()]; // this too
          document.getElementById("titulo"+i).innerHTML =day;
          document.getElementById("fecha"+i).innerHTML = moment(d).locale("es").format('LLL');
          d.setDate(d.getDate() +1); // Need to change this to functionality moment

      }
  }
```

Alredy try to remove d variable, but the *for* stop working, its possibly change this function to full moment.js but with the same functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First place all on a `Rendered Function`

```
          Meteor.call('tomaFecha',function(error,fecha){
                  if(error){
                    console.log("no se pudo mostrar la fecha");
                  } else { 
                    dia = moment(fecha).locale("es");
                    var d = dia;
                          for (i=1; i<8;i++){  
                               document.getElementById("sub"+i).innerHTML = d.format('L');
                               document.getElementById("titulo"+i).innerHTML = d.format('dddd');
                              // document.getElementById("dia"+i).innerHTML = d.format('dddd');
                               //document.getElementById("fecha"+i).innerHTML = d.format('LLL');
                               d.add(1,'days');
                          }
                  }
     });
```

Also we use a `Meteor.call`, to get the server time, and ignore the browser time

**Server.js**

```
    Meteor.methods({
  tomaFecha : function(){
    var d = (new Date())
   return d;
  }
})
```

And it works